# Using Drupal 7 & Omega 3.x - Page Titles + Edit Tabs are not showing up on node content types!

Tags: blocks, theming, 7

It seems that my page titles and the edit tabs have disappeared. I'm currently using omega 3.x and drupal 7. However the weird thing is that its showing up one content type, but not on others. I even created a new content type and it still doesnt show up. I also disabled the theme and enabled the default seven theme as the main one and it does show up. So it is in fact omega's subtheme that is causing the issue when i enable it.

Comment: What templates are in place? What panels/panelizer/panels everywhere configuration do you have on those paths?

Answer (score 1):

it seems that it is a bug in omega. https://www.drupal.org/node/1906744 -- this took quite awhile to figure it out! The culprit was actually the "main content" block not being enabled on the blocks page. This was because I was primarily using context in positioning my blocks and left the default blocks page empty by not assigning anything. It seems that the theme has to detect the "main content" block in order to show the tabs. So the fix is just assigning the "main content" block back into the content region.